# How to bind an element of a directive from a parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a directive, and in the template I have another directive.

```
<parent-directive>
```

parent-directive-template.html:

```
<div>
  <child-directive>
</div>
```

child-directive-template:

```
<input id="bind-me" />
```

Fully compiled it should look like this:

```
<div>
   <input id="bind-me" />
</div>
```

The parent direct in the link function wants to bind to the input's events but it cannot as it seems like the child directive is not yet compiled!

I logged the pre and post links for each and I get this ordering:

1. 'parent-prelink'
2. 'parent-postlink'
3. 'child-prelink'
4. 'child-postlink'

I don't understand then how I can bind to the child-directives input element (found in the child directives template). They both use templateUrl however both templates are cached, so this is probably not an issue.

Comment: What I would recommend is that on the `parent-directive`'s controller you create an item called `link_child` which is a function that takes whatever it is you need in order to link them together correctly. Then, in `child-directive`'s controller call the `parent_controller.link_child()` function with whatever arguments you need (say the element itself, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for the existence of the input and bind when that is available.

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  var unWatch = scope.$watch(
      function() {
        return element.find('$bind-me');
      },
      function (input) {
        if (input.length > 0) {
          unWatch();
          // bind here
        }
      }
  );
}
```